# Reusing windows clock control from timedate.cpl?

Tags: .net, winapi

I'm trying to reuse windows clock that exist in `timedate.cpl` which is a dll, I know how to communicate with it using `SendMessage` to get and set time. My problem is this control is a private window class so i tried to load the dll first then create a window with name `ClockWndMain` but it fails and the reason is `window class name is not valid.`.

My question is how could i create a window of this control?

Comment: Let's say you figure this out.  What is your application going to do when someone in Windows-land decides to update the control and thus break your application?  I suspect that the control is private because the developers who wrote the control didn't want to have to worry about 3rd party developers re-using the control.

Comment: the control is not related to neither timedate.cpl nor system time,
use SendMessage with Message CLM_UPDATETIME = WM_USER + 102, when wParam is CLF_GETTIME = 0 then lParam must be user allocated LPSYSTEMTIME that will filled with the time saved in it, when wParam is CLF_SETTIME = 1 then lParam must be user allocated LPSYSTEMTIME that contains the time to be set.

Comment: correction to my last comment: LPSYSTEMTIME can be in stack, you don't have to allocate it in heap. all you need is to pass a vaild pointer to SYSTEMTIME in lParam.